# What happens when a stock gets removed from the exchange I used to buy it?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, brokerage, spain

I own stocks of *Siemens Gamesa* which I (foolishly) bought via the *XETRA* stock exchange instead of the more liquid Spanish *Mercado Continuo*. The stock has always received little attention and liquidity on *XETRA*, but some days ago **it stopped getting new quotations altogether**. The stock is still being traded on other exchanges, like the Spanish stock exchange, just not on *XETRA*. So I investigated the issue and found this [**removal notification** from XETRA](http://www.xetra.com/xetra-en/newsroom/mifid-ii-releases!suspension-view?ts=1547805601000&issuer&instrument=ES0143416115).

This leads me to the following questions:

1. **Why has this happened?** It's not a complete delisting of the company (they are not going private), it is still being traded on other exchanges under the same ISIN. The category of the news entry containing *MiFID II* suggests that it is a regulatory issue.
2. **What should I do now and what can I reasonably expect from by broker?** I don't intend to sell the stock at the moment, but I do want to be able to sell the stock quickly when the moment comes. And I don't want to miss any deadlines in case there is action required from my side. Can the stock be "moved" to a different exchange by my broker? Can they charge me a fee for that? My broker hadn't informed me about this beforehand.

Update: I am in Spain and the broker is a Spanish bank.

Comment: If you’re paying a broker for the trade they should certainly answer these types of questions for you. Are you also in Spain? Your country’s securities laws affect this so please update the question with your location. Also we can guess that they removed it because they didn’t find it profitable to trade in that stock.

Comment: @T.M. Surely the broker should be able to tell me all that. I just like to be informed and to know beforehand what to expect and what is reasonable. Updated location.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your shares are in no way linked to the exchange you bought them on. You can sell them in any exchange your broker has access to.

Comment: Well, they do appear linked to XETRA in the broker interface, and placing orders doesn't work. So at least in my broker's system they are linked. So you are saying that it's basically only a matter of telling the broker which alternative exchange I prefer and the broker changing a flag in its database?

Comment: @Weirdo At least, it should be that way, yes.

Comment: Or if your broker doesn't deal with the exchange in question, have the shares transferred to a broker that does.